# How to Update a single column through informatica?

Tags: row, updates, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a target table with the following attributes:

```
PARTY_ID PK
START_DATE PK
STATUS_CD PK
END_DATE
```

I have a dynamic lookup which is returning me 1(insert) 2(update) 0 (duplicate) for each row from source table.

What i want is when i get 2(update) to add an END_DATE to the updated row without changing anything else.

For example i have the following row in my target table:

```
1 12/01/2014 2 NULL
```

and i get this row from my source table:

```
1 14/01/2014 6 NULL
```

What i want is to add ONLY the end date to the target table without anything else. LIKE:

```
1 12/01/2014 2 14/01/2014
```

I know how to update the whole row but i dont know how to update only one column.

Schema:

```
CREATE SET TABLE IND_MAR_STATUS ,NO FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
 (
  INDIVIDUAL_PARTY_ID DECIMAL(18,0) NOT NULL,
  INDIV_MARITAL_STAT_START_DTTM DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' NOT NULL,
  MARITAL_STATUS_CD VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  INDIV_MARITAL_STAT_END_DTTM DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  ETL_SOURCE_ID DECIMAL(18,0) NOT NULL,
  ETL_EXTRACT_SPEC_ID DECIMAL(18,0),
  ETL_JOB_RUN_ID DECIMAL(18,0))
PRIMARY INDEX ( INDIVIDUAL_PARTY_ID );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply disconnect the target ports you don't want to update (i.e. only PARTY_ID and END_DATE should be connected).

Comment: I have an update strategy where i am checking if the flag that i am getting is 0(reject) 1(insert) 2(update). If i connect only the end date port for the update it will not work because if i have an insert it will need all the ports!

Comment: You can use a router and separate instances of the target for inserting and updating.

Comment: I will add the schema of my table so you can understand how it is

Comment: UPDATE: 
IT IS WORKING! 

But i have three same target tables.!! Which is not a good practice. I have this because i have three update strategies. One for updating a single column. One for insert and one for inserting the updated row as new.

Comment: I added a picture too

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad practice? Imagine you have only one target and you are checking information in the Wofkflow Monitor - are you able to tell whether rows were update or inserted? Just make sure the targets have meaningful names.